# How to delete non-exist project from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have a non-exist project which I am unable to remove from Eclipse. I am just checking if there is any other way to remove it.

Process of deleting project I am using:

Selecting project -> right click -> select delete -> follow the wizards

Result: `a fatal error occured while performing the refactoring`
found-problem `client-target does not exist anymore`[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like your workspace is corrupted, try deleting and creating new owrkspace

Comment: Can you try deleting from the "Navigator" view (Window -> Show View -> Navigator)? Select project and hit Delete...

Comment: It looks like you are getting that error from something that is refactoring after you removed something else.  The entire work area probably refreshes/refactors.  And now there is a disconnect with one of your other projects.  (That's what it looks like to me.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try this :

- Close your workspace :
- Delete the dir `client-target`   from `<workspaceDir>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects`
- Open your workspace

And should be good

Comment: Do not do this!

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau could you explain why not to do this?

Comment: @AJPerez It will remove all projects from your workspace, not just the non-existing ones.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau i said to delete the directory "client-target" that refere to the project from the initial question not the ".projects" directory

Comment: Works for me, but after deleting the directory, I also had to click `File` -> `Refresh` to get it to work.

Comment: But make sure you don't have any project selected, or it would only update that project.

Answer (score 41):

VinyJones answer did not work for me, since there was no corresponding metadata for the non-existant project. The solution for me was to drag the non-existing project to an other working set. After dragging it disappeared.

Comment: Just to confirm that this solution also worked for me, without a restart. Should be tried before accepted answer (delete directory from .metadata).

Comment: This worked for me instead of the accepted answer, too. I had to drag the project onto the "Other Projects" working set folder, though. Another "real" working set did not work.

Comment: Works, and is dead simple to do.

Comment: Hmm, this did not work for me – the project just appeared in the new working set instead.

Comment: I'm still running Eclipse 2018-12 (on Linux). While the first time I moved the project it was still shown in the package explorer, I moved it again and it disappeared. Really odd behavior but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

none of the above worked for me but this solution worked (was really a ghost project)

1. Shut down Eclipse
2. Open `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml`
3. Find the faulty  tag and remove it
4. Start Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For me neither solution worked.
I'd to go to "Select working set" then select "Windows working sets".
The project then appeared without working set and I was finally able to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Running Eclipse with the `-clean` command line parameter works also.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the same error message when trying to remove the project.

Answer (score -1):

I found all the answers here to be a little too elaborate and/or risky. So I closed eclipse (actually I had to force delete its sad, broken husk from Task Manager) then started it again.

Then I was able to right-click delete the packages from the package explorer.

Sounds like the solutions here are red/black on the roulette wheel. Maybe one of them will work for somebody? I miss .NET!